# Laravel: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$game

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm making a game by using PHP and Laravel. And now I want to store some records like games played, the wins they received and the losts. But how can I save those records for the User that has logged in?

I tried this, but I get the error (Title of the post);

```
    public function winGame() {
    if(isset(Auth::user()->email)) {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

        $games = $user->statuses()->game;
        $gamesPlus = $games + 1;

        $wins = $user->statuses()->wins;
        $winsPlus = $wins + 1;

        $user->statuses()->save($gamesPlus, $winsPlus);
    }
}
```

And I may not use the DB:: method only the Model name.

Model User:

```
public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Status');
}
```

Model Status:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: do the status has a model also ?

Comment: You need to add more details, like the user model where you defined the relation. describe the other entities and their relation with the user model. what attribute you want to update ? btw `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` is useless, change it to `$user = Auth::user();` For the error, you're trying to access an attribute on a query builder via relation.

Comment: Since it's a `hasMany`, you need to iterate through the different statuses. Or change it to a hasOne relationship, in which case you can make the code a lot easier by just modifying the existing record.

Comment: Yea the status has a model, I used hasMany instead of hasOne but hasOne is also not working.

Comment: `()` retrieves the query builder for database queries. Drop that to just get the single record/relationship collection.

Comment: I edited my post by adding the models

Comment: Where do I have to drop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `()` on statuses retrieves the query builder, not the record. You can easily clean up the code by doing this to increment the individual rows by one.

```
public function winGame() {
    if(isset(Auth::user()->email)) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->statuses->game++;
        $user->statuses->wins++;

        $user->statuses->save();
    }
}
```

Or, even slightly more readable,

```
public function winGame() {
    if(isset(Auth::user()->email)) {
        $status = Auth::user()->statuses;

        $status->game++;
        $status->wins++;

        $status->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: game (SQL: update "statuses" set "wins" = 1, "game" = 1, "updated_at" = 2020-01-17 16:51:33 where "id" = 1)

Comment: You'll need to take a look at your statuses table to see what columns it has and what it should be updating.

Comment: Never mind I have to use games instead of game, thank you!!